# Syntax Error in SQL Query( select ) when an empty list is passed

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I'm running SQL Query using python-Django RAW Query..!!

I'm using **IN()** function to pass my tuple in the query.

My code looks like this...

Here I am getting the list of `dnc_domains` and `dnc_company` from a json/function

```
dnc_domain_names = list(map(lambda x: get_domain_name(x), dnc_websites))
dnc_company_names = list(map(lambda l: l.lower(), list(filter(None, list(map(lambda x: x['company_name'], dnc_info))))))
```

QUERY:

```
select_query = """
                   select c.id
                   from (
                         select id, lower(company_name) as c_name,substring(website from '(?:.*://)?(?:www\.)?([^/]*)') as website_domain, 
                         from contacts 
                         where campaign_id = %s
                         ) c
                   where
                    c.c_name IN %s 
                    OR c.website_domain IN %s
                 """
```

Executing Query:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
     cursor.execute(select_query, (campaign.id,tuple(dnc_company_names),tuple(dnc_domain_names))
     matching_contact_ids = cursor.fetchall()
```

But, there is a case when any `dnc_company_names` or `dnc_domain_name` is **empty []** then my Query throws an Error otherwise if there at least 1 element in any of them then it works fine.

SQL Error:

```
syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 5:                                 WHERE id IN ()
                                                     ^
```

So, help me to tackle this error. SQL should handle both empty or non empty tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved by providing `NULL` values in list

```
if not dnc_company_name:
    dnc_company_name = [None]
```

finally, in my question, I am converting `dnc_company_name` into `tuple`.

and it solved my problem.

Comment: But even when your list have single element and you convert it into tuple, that will end up in a format this format. (1,) you cant pass a tuple with ","  as a IN parameter.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table UPDATE  column = 1 WHERE id IN (155693,)` This dont work.

Answer (score -4):

The right part of the IN must be a subquery returning exactly one column:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN

I tried

```
SELECT *
FROM table_with_data 
WHERE toto IN (SELECT * FROM empty);
```

which throws this error:

> ERROR: subquery has too few columns

I guess you should provide something as **IN (NULL)** in the case your columns are strictly NOT NULL.

Comment: In my case, I'm using JSON data from another file in the ```IN()``` function and not the subquery from another table